# Creating a nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, dynamic-arrays

I apparently cannot think abstractly enough to do this... but I'd like to create a Javascript object out of an array that uses the array values as property names, but they should be nested objects within each other.

So if I had an array like this:

```
['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

My expected output would be:

```
{
    First: {
        Second: {
            Third: {
                Fourth: {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the function I was using as mentioned in the commment:

```
function appendKey(obj, to, key) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(to)) {
        appendKey(obj[to], to, key);
    } else {
        obj[key] = {};
    }

    return obj;
}
```

My intent was to call it as such:

```
var data = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];
data = appendKey(data, 'First', 'Second');
data = appendKey(data, 'Second', 'Third');
data = appendKey(data, 'Third', 'Fourth');
```

Clearly that could be put into a loop, which is why I wanted to do it that way. My output ended up being:

```
data = { 'First' : { 'Second' } } // it works this time!

data = { 'First' : { 'Second' },
         'Third' : { } }

data = { 'First' : { 'Second' },
         'Third' : { 'Fourth' { } } }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried a self-calling function that takes in the object as-is and the key you want to add. If the key doesnt exist, add it to the passed object and return it. If the key exists, it calls itself again but with the `object.key` in the first parameter.

Comment: @HonusWagner: What did it do, and what didn’t it do?  Could you show us the code?

Comment: I think my approach would work if the object was by value rather than reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside the loop, store your base object in a variable, and have a separate variable to store the current object *(which starts off being the same as the base)*.

Inside the loop, take the "current" object, give it a key using the current array member, assign a new object to that key, and make that new object the new "current" object.

```
var arr = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'],
    obj = {},
    currObj = obj;

arr.forEach(function(key) {
    currObj = (currObj[key] = {});
});

console.log(obj); // {First:{Second:{Third:{Fourth:{}}}}}
```

*DEMO:* http://jsfiddle.net/qunDt/

---

You can unwind the code in the `forEach`  a bit if you prefer.

```
arr.forEach(function(key) {
    currObj[key] = {};
    currObj = currObj[key];
});
```

---

If you wanted a purely recursive approach, you could do it like this:

```
function nested(list, o) {
    if (list.length === 0)
        return o;
    o[list.shift()] = nested(list, {})
    return o;
}

var obj = nested(arr, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'];

var build = function(soFar,remaining) {
    if(remaining.length === 0) {return soFar;}
    var outer = {};
    outer[names.pop()] = soFar;
    return build(outer, names);
}

var result = build({}, names);
```